# Does DisplayTag PaginatedList work with external sorting?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag

I am using [DisplayTag 1.2](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/displaytag/) with Struts2 and having exactly the same problem as described [here](http://osdir.com/ml/java-displaytag-general/2007-07/msg00039.html), namely:

- I have implemented the [`PaginatedList`](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/apidocs/org/displaytag/pagination/PaginatedList.html) interface and displaying my paginated data (*sans* sorting) works fine.
- But DisplayTag seems to be ignoring the `<column sortName="...">` attribute and just using the string from the `property` attribute.
- Moreover, if I have a `<column ...>` element that uses a nested Struts2 `<s:property ...>` element for its value instead of the `<column property="...">` attribute, DisplayTag sets the sort criteria to blank!

Is this a bug? If so, is there a version of DisplayTag for which this bug has been fixed? Is there a way to use the `PaginatedList` interface *and* set the key string DisplayTag picks as the sort criteria for each table column?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very well documented, but from reading the code on GrepCode, I figured it out:

You can use the `<column sortProperty="...">` attribute to set an arbitrary sort key string for the column. So use **`sortProperty`**, not `sortName`!